# How to close current tab using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to close current tab using javascript/Jquery. But I did not find any solution. I read that the window.close() only works with window which is open with `window.open()` method. So is there any way to send command to system that user press ctrl+w which is also close this window. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZXXWz/)

```
function down(){
window.close()
}
```

Comment: read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1419307/close-windows-or-tabs-on-a-button-click

Comment: possible duplicate of [Closing the Browser tab using js or jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8411978/closing-the-browser-tab-using-js-or-jquery)

Comment: I think you can only close a tab that was opened using Javascript.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12896858/2519416

Comment: Long answer, it's not possible. read this [window.close](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.close).`When this method is called, the referenced window is closed.`In you demo, the `window` referenced a iframe, which is embeded in the page.So, the `window.close` is not working.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window)

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It is possible. I searched the whole internet for this, but once when i took one of Microsoft's survey, I finally got the answer.

try this:

```
window.top.close();
```

this will close the current tab for you.

Comment: I try to do this into firefox but It's not working there.

Comment: Scripts may close only the windows that were opened by it.

Answer (score 5):

This seems to work from a previous thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18776480/3642027

However, from my testing, it only works if it's a fresh link opened with `target="_blank"`.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest this little function JS, it works on Chrome 54.0.2840.99

```
function closeWin() { 
    window.top.close();
}
setTimeout(function(){ 
    closeWin()
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the actual answer is obsolete because of security issues the closest working solution i found today is

open(location, '_self').close();

I also recommend to check this thread where i got the code from its many authors:
[How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2076299/how-to-close-current-tab-in-a-browser-window?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 2):

I searched about it, someone wrote you can not close it until unless, you opened by code or pro-grammatically It was convincing but I found later and it worked for me. hope so it help you too.

var win = window.open("about:blank", "_self");

win.close();

Comment: This answer is fundamentally the same as [this answer from Sept '19](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57970545/215552), and is very similar to the answers on the duplicate 10 year old question, [How to close current tab in a browser window?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2076299/215552).

Answer (score -1):

Here a HTML Code **witout** javascript:

```html
<a href="about:blank" target="">&#10006;</a>
```

Here with a nice design:

```html
<a style="color:black; text-decoration:none;" href="about:blank" target="">
  <button style="position: fixed; top:2px; right:2px; border: 1px solid black; background: red; cursor: pointer; z-index: 2;">
    &#10006;
  </button>
</a>
```

Comment: it will not close the current tab, but only shows white page