# How to close browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am not able to close the current browser tab using javascript.

I tried-

```
    window.close(); //1

    window.open("", '_self');//2
    setTimeout(function(){
        window.close();
    },100);

    window.open('','_parent',''); //3
    window.close();

    window.top.opener=null; //4
    window.close();
```

**Nothing is working for me in chrome**

Comment: Can you elaborate with more details or fiddle... coz window.close() works in all cases

Comment: I would not bet that javascript can always close a tab as it's most likely linked to browser security settings.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

window.close method is only allowed to be called for windows that were opened by a script using the window.open method.

Comment: That's what i am trying to do in the second method. I am opening it by javascript and then closing it.

Answer (score 6):

```
window.open('', '_self', '').close();
```

See my original answer on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48854816/1837643)

Answer (score 1):

As much as I know, you can't close browser tab using Javascript. This is not a common way to do...

I'm not sure if you can do this, because some browsers do not have any tabs at all...

But try this, may be it work for you :

```
window.top.close();
```

reference : [Another Question in stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857363/how-to-close-current-tab-using-javascript)

**OR :**

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_self').close();">close</a>
```

Comment: Where do you use this? Check if you're trigger is ok... Ask javascript to make an `alert` or use `console.log`where you want to use this, for example...

Answer (score 0):

You can only close windows/tabs that you create yourself. That is, you cannot programmatically close a window/tab that the user creates.

For example, if you create a window with `window.open()` you can close it with `window.close()`.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated, you can only close windows/tabs that you previously opened yourself. None of your code snippets comply with this.

If you want to close a child window from its parent you need to store a reference to it, e.g.:

```
var child = window.open("");
setTimeout(function(){
    child.close();
},100);
```

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/tireyaxilo/edit?js,output)

If you want to close the child window from itself you need to run the code inside the window.

If you overwrite current document with a blank one your your code disappears.

---

Now, Chrome is a special beast. It opens each tab in a different process. That means that several good old techniques that involve different tabs do not work at all. For instance, you can't even use the target parameter in window.open() to share a window.

Comment: I want to close the same window.In my code i am trying to open the same window and then close it by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script>
    var win;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = 'this tab url';
        win = window.open(url, '_self');
        window.stop();                
    });
    function closeWindow() {
        win.close();
    }
</script>
```

**Then in html**

```
<a href="javascript:closeWindow();">close</a>
```

**If there are multiple tusk to load then wait some times by this**

```
setTimeout(
  function() 
  {
    //do something special
   //window.stop(); 
  }, 5000);
```

Comment: I don't want to close the tab on click. It should happen without users interaction.