# Javascript check ctrl+s

Tags: javascript, jquery, keyboard

I'm new to js. How can I check if the client press the key combination <kbd>ctl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd>?

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
  if(e.charCode == 17 && e.charCode == 83) {
    alert("ok");
  }
});
```

This doesn't work. Jquery is included.

Comment: Have you checked your browser console for any errors? Also please note `83` is uppercase **S** and `115` is lowercase **s**

Comment: How would it be possible, that `e.charCode` would be 17 and 83 at the same time?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best cross-browser method to capture CTRL+S with JQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93695/best-cross-browser-method-to-capture-ctrls-with-jquery)

Comment: @NewToJS No erros in the console.
Only one of them does not working too.

Comment: I would just like to add that behaviour expected from "ctrl + s" (on windows and linux) is normally expected from "cmd + s" on macOS, so (depending on what you would like to achieve) you might want to add handling for that too :)

Answer (score 3):

This would work if you are jQuery.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).keydown(function(event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode == 83) {
      event.preventDefault()
      //action here
      alert('Saved');
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Press ctrl +s
```

Working [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ww3b5ktf/).

If you want to detect `cmd + s` on mac, you need to use keycodes mentioned below on different-different browsers, beacuse unlike Shift/Alt/Ctrl, Mac/Apple key is not considered as a modifier key--instead, you should hook on keydown/keyup and record when a key is pressed:

```
Firefox: 224
Opera: 17
WebKit (Safari/Chrome): 91 (Left Apple) or 93 (Right Apple)
```

I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902635/how-does-one-capture-a-macs-command-key-via-javascript).

And if you want close your browser tab on save `window.top.close();` will work that I got from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857363/how-to-close-current-tab-using-javascript). Also working for me.

Comment: you should use `event.which` instead of `event.keyCode` :)

Comment: And how can I exit the save process from the browser?

Comment: @Markus it should not come up at all

Comment: I dont think so. It will log my message and open the "Save File" dialog. http://prntscr.com/fyhexv

Comment: @Markus Added fiddle also.