# How to close the Current opened Tab and go back to previous (Parent) Tab

Tags: javascript

**It is not a duplicate question please** 
Dear All,
I am new to Jquery, Please help me how to close the Current opened Tab in a application using Jquery on click of YES/Confirm button in a model window as shown in a image.
I have tried below function, its not closing current tab instead it closed all the tabs. Please help me
  [image]

```
window.open('', '_self').close();
         window.top.close();
         window.close();
```

Comment: JavaScript can't manipulate tabs.

Comment: Since i am opening the window/tab not using window.open so. I am able to close the particular tab by TabID using programmatically

Comment: JS can only close a window/tab that it opened. If you don't use `window.open`, you can't close it.

Comment: **I am able to close the particular tab by TabID using programmatically** You keep stating that, but it's not true. Why do you think you're able to do that? Where do you get the TabID from?

Comment: I think a browser extension can do this, but not JavaScript in an ordinary page.

Answer (score 2):

before you close the current tab, you need to open it using "window.open()". 
the window.close button works only the windows that opened by it.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as i have mentioned I am not opening the window using windo.open, so could you please help me, how I can close the parent window from the modal window as shown in the image

Comment: Since i am opening the window/tab not using window.open so. I am able to close the particular tab by TabID using programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You can close the current tab with this javascript line:

```
window.top.close();
```

But there are things that you should keep in mind:

- This will only work if the tab is also opened programmatically.

  By using `window.open();`, you can close the opened tab with the javascript line above.
- Not all browsers support this solution

You can also visit [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857363/how-to-close-current-tab-using-javascript,) for reference. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response, as i have mentioned I am not opening the window using windo.open, so could you please help me, how I can close the parent window from the modal window as shown in the image

Comment: Hi @Shankar. Well on that case, you cannot close the tab. Javascript can't manipulate tabs that are not opened programmatically.

Comment: Thanks again, but there has to be way to identify the tab name and close right ? in my case, I have the tab name ,

Comment: @Shankar You still can't. You'll only get this notification when trying to close the specified tab `"Scripts may not close windows that were not opened by script"`

Comment: `window.top` is the top window that contains the current iframe. It can't be used to refer to a completely different tab in the browser.